# DropDownChoice onSelectionChnaged

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, wicket

```
DropDownChoice<Bean> groupDDC =new DropDownChoice<Bean>(....) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(Bean newSelection) {
    super.onSelectionChanged(newSelection);
    // my logic

    }
}
```

`super.onSelectionChanged(newSelection);` is pre-written in the `onSlectionChnaged` method.

I can remove that code or I can keep that and add my code below that, it all works the same.

So my question is, is it better to keep that code? And why?

Note : I am using wicket 1.4.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DropDownChoice#onSelectionChanged() is an empty hook method, you don't need to call it from your override.

Comment: Hmm, I see, saw the ,method definition, nothing in the body.